# javascript method chaining not working

Tags: javascript

Have a literal object with methods.

I want to chain the methods to each other using appendChild DOM method.
In the createStructure method if i separate the assignmentsd from each other, works.

```
var row = this.createRow();
row.appendChild(this.createHeadCells());
this.DBTable.appendChild(row);
```

If i chain the methods to each other it wont, no error message.

```
this.DBTable.appendChild(this.createRow().appendChild(this.createHeadCells()));
```

Otherwise this chaining is working:

```
document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('p').appendChild(document.createElement('span').appendChild(document.createTextNode('abc')));
```

What did i wrong?

The Code:

```
var readyStateCheckInterval = setInterval(function () {
    if (document.readyState === "complete" || document.readyState === "loaded") {
        clearInterval(readyStateCheckInterval);
        init();
    }
}, 10);

var DBTable =
{
    DBTable : document.createDocumentFragment(),
    colNum : 0,
    rowNum : 0,

    createTable : function(colNum, rowNum)
    {
        this.DBTable = document.createElement('table');
        this.colNum = colNum;
        this.rowNum = rowNum;

        this.createTableStructure();
    },

    createRow : function()
    {
        return document.createElement('tr');
    },

    createHeadCells : function()
    {
        var df = document.createDocumentFragment();

        for ( var a = 0; a < this.colNum; a++)
        {
            df.appendChild(document.createElement('th'));
        }
        return df;
    },

    createDataCells : function()
    {
        var df = document.createDocumentFragment();

        for ( var a = 0; a < this.colNum; a++)
        {
            df.appendChild(document.createElement('td'));
        }
        return df;
    },

    createTableStructure : function()
    {
        var row = this.createRow();
        row.appendChild(this.createHeadCells());
        this.DBTable.appendChild(row);
        this.DBTable.appendChild(this.createRow().appendChild(this.createHeadCells()));
/*
        for ( var a = 0; a < this.rowNum; a++) {
            var row = this.createRow();
            row.appendChild(this.createDataCells());
            this.DBTable.appendChild(row);
            //this.DBTable.appendChild(this.createRow().appendChild(this.createDataCells()));
        }
*/
        document.body.appendChild(this.DBTable);
    }
};

function init() {


    DBTable.createTable(3,4);
    var td = document.querySelectorAll('td');
    for (var el in td) {
        td[el].innerHTML = 'asdf';
    }

    var th = document.querySelectorAll('th');
    for (var el2 in th) {
        th[el2].innerHTML = 'abcd';
    }

}
```

Comment: What is `init()` ?

Comment: init is a pure function wich is executed when the document is loaded.
The rest of the document is there. Added to the question body.

Comment: Chaining is cool. However, I have to say it's declining in popularity. It's more work than it's worth.